# Terraform.tf parameterize or template for different environment

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

This is the terraform.tf file. I want to give different values based on the environment for 'name' field. How can I do it?

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "=2.46.0"
    features {}
}

terraform {
    backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name = "rgtstate"
        storage_account_name = "adststorage"
        container_name = "terraform.tfstate"
  #      access_key = ""
    }
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
    name = "sk-terraform-rg"
    location = "west europe"
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {

  name                = "adfSB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_self_hosted" "example" {
  name                = "VMSHIRSB"
  data_factory_name   = azurerm_data_factory.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give different values based on the environment for the 'name' field, if you want the same configuration `main.tf` file for defining multiple environments, you can declare the environment `variable "env" {}` then use the `var.env` prefix on the name filed in each resource in different environments. You can create each resource dynamically by passing a different environment variable.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
    name = "${var.env}-terraform-rg"
    location = "west europe"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {

  name                = "${var.env}-adfSB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_self_hosted" "example" {
  name                = "${var.env}-VMSHIRSB"
  data_factory_name   = azurerm_data_factory.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
}
```

If you want to create separate configurations file for different environments, you can create directories. When you are finished separating these environments into directories, your file structure should look like the one below.

```
.
├── assets
│   ├── index.html
├── prod
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── variables.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   └── terraform.tfvars
└── dev
   ├── main.tf
   ├── variables.tf
   ├── terraform.tfstate
   └── terraform.tfvars
```

In this scenario, you will have duplicate Terraform code in each directory.

If you want to use the same Terraform code but have different state files, you can use [workspace-separated](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/organize-configuration#state-storage-in-workspaces) environments. You could define `variable "dev_prefix" {}` or `variable "prod_prefix" {}`

Your directory will look similar to the one below.

```
.
├── README.md
├── assets
│   └── index.html
├── dev.tfvars
├── main.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── prod.tfvars
├── terraform.tfstate.d
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── terraform.tfstate
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── terraform.tfstate
├── terraform.tfvars
└── variables.tf
```

In this scenario, if you want to be able to declare variables that give us selection control, you can refer to [this](https://medium.com/@milescollier/handling-environmental-variables-in-terraform-workspaces-27d0278423df). Read [here](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/deploying-multiple-environments-with-terraform-kubernetes-7b7f389e622) for more details about workspace and modules.